# I have a conflict Matrix, and a list of users with different access, I want to check whether the user as a conflicting access or not

Tags: sql, excel

Conflict Matrix: C = conflict, A = accessible, X = same

**Conflict Matrix** is as below image

[image]

Using the above table as an example, if I wanted to find the access for A & B I would look down the first column for A, and across the first row for B.
The intersection of these two letters would return C for Conflict.

Comment: plz add a proper requirement with your expected output to make it more understandable!

Comment: The above image is the conflict matrix, and i have list of users for example user "sam" as access A and B which is a conflict, like that I want to check for all the user and get the  list of users who have conflict as output

Comment: *make it clear* 1.mention RDBMS name 2.Input is SQL table/view or excel? 3. Output format

Comment: Input is Excel file with user list, output in excel

Answer (score 0):

If your data table is in cells `A1:I9` and your key lookup is in cells `K1:L3` (i.e `K1` contains **C**, `L1` is **Conflict**)  you can use a combination of `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

- `MATCH("A",$A$1:$A$9,0)` will return the row number that `A` appears in on column A.
- `MATCH("B",$A$1:$I$1,0)` will return the column number that `B` appears in on row 1.
- `INDEX($A$1:$I$9, RowNum, ColumnNum)` will return the value at the intersection of *RowNum* & *ColumnNum*
- `VLOOKUP(ReturnedValue,$K$1:$L$3,2,FALSE)` will return the looked up value of C, A or X.

Stick the four formula together to get your final result (change "A" & "B" to the access values you're looking for:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX($A$1:$I$9,MATCH("A",$A$1:$A$9,0),MATCH("B",$A$1:$I$1,0)),$K$1:$L$3,2,FALSE)
```

Further reading:

[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
[INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
[VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)